# hibernate with JPA to generate entity in other schema

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have created two entities in my JAVA code one is Account entity, another is AccountLog entity. These two entities mapped to the corresponding   table in same schema named testdb. We use hibernate and JPA to handle the insert/update and table generation.

Since the performance issue, I would like to separate the AccountLog into other schema named testdb_log. So that the AccountLog table will be generated in schema testdb_log and the next insert/update event will be stored in the schema testdb_log.

What is the best solution to handle the above cases? Add @table annotation with schema name? or others?

1. How to generate the entity to other schema?
2. For this entity, how to save/update this entity information to other schema?

Answer (score 0):

I will probably use different persistence units in the persistence xml, something like this:

```
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="oneschema" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driver}" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${datasource.baseurl}/SCHEMAONE" />
            <property name="user" value="${datasource.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="anotherchema" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.company.AccountLog</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driver}" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${datasource.baseurl}/SCHEMANOTHER" />
            <property name="user" value="${datasource.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In the second persistence unit you declare explicitly what classes belong to it, so the entity manager will know how to deal with them.

Schema, connections, connection pools are usually transparent to the java code so you shouldn't change anything in java.